# Java batch processing job listener afterJob get id of a job

Tags: java, batch-processing, jobs

How can detect a job id of finished job that is calling afterJob listener?
I have job that is starting in batch processing and i have listener.

My job is called PayrollJob and the listener is PayrollJobListener

```
<job id="payroll" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.0">
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="payrollJobListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <step id="process">
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="payrollItemWriteListener"/>
            <listener ref="payrollSkipProcessorListener"/>
            <listener ref="payrollSkipReadListener"/>
            <listener ref="payrollSkipWriteListener"/>
            <listener ref="payrollChunkListener"/>

        </listeners>
        <chunk item-count="5">
            <reader ref="PayrollItemReader"></reader> 
            <processor ref="PayrollItemProcessor"></processor>
            <writer ref="PayrollItemWriter"></writer> 



        </chunk>
    </step>
</job>
```

and class with listener

```
@Named()
public class PayrollJobListener extends AbstractJobListener {

    @Override()
    public void beforeJob(){};

    @Override()
    public void afterJob(){
        System.out.println("i need a id of a job calling this method");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a JobContext.

```
@Named()
public class PayrollJobListener extends AbstractJobListener {

    @Inject
    private JobContext jobContext;

    @Override()
    public void beforeJob(){};

    @Override()
    public void afterJob(){
        long id = this.jobContext.getExecutionId();
        String name = this.jobContext.getJobName();
    };
}
```